# Определение максимального значения битового поля

Tags: c++, структуры, битовые-операции

Есть такая структура

```cpp
struct test {
  uint8_t a: 4;
  uint8_t b: 3;
}
```

Мне нужно определить какое максимальное число я могу записать в поле. Т.е. нужно что-то типа этого

```cpp
#define MAX_A ((1 << size_of_bits(test::a)) - 1)
#define MAX_B ((1 << size_of_bits(test::b)) - 1)
```

Все, что придумал, это сделать так

```cpp
#define LEN_A 4
#define LEN_B 3

struct test {
  uint8_t a: LEN_A;
  uint8_t b: LEN_B;
}

#define MAX_A ((1 << LEN_A) - 1)
#define MAX_B ((1 << LEN_B) - 1)
```

Есть еще варианты без определения первых двух дефайнов?

Comment: Использовать `const` или `constexpr` вместо макросов

Comment: @dIm0n но все равно мне придется отдельно объявлять `LEN_X`. А без этого?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20194009/13970074

Answer (score 2):

А такой вариант?

```
test t;
t.a = 1;
int s = 0;
for(;t.a; t.a<<=1) s++;
cout << (1<<s)-1 << endl;
```

Везде `unsigned`, так что вроде бы все корректно...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Тогда уже проще макросами. И где-то я встречал фразу, что поведение при переполнении битового поля зависит от реализации компилятора